How to create animated GIF from a sequence of image files?
I tried this command line:
D:\Captured>ffmpeg -framerate 1/2 -start_number 1 -i "D:/New folder (76)/Image%d.png" -loop -1 D:/test.gif

But getting this error:
[image2 @ 00000000026324a0] Could find no file with path 'D:/New folder (76)/Image%d.png' and index in the range 1-5 D:/New folder (76)/Image%d.png: No such file or directory

Here is a screenshot image of my folder with the images and I want to get only the images type png that start with the name image:


Update: Here is the message I get after creating the animated GIF including the command line from this answer:
D:\Captured>ffmpeg -framerate 1/2 -start_number 1 -i "D:/New folder (76)/Image_%04d.png" -loop -1 D:/test.gif
ffmpeg version n6.1.1-20240114 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 13.2.0 (crosstool-NG 1.25.0.232_c175b21)
  configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-libxml2 --enable-zlib --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libvorbis --enable-opencl --disable-libpulse --enable-libvmaf --disable-libxcb --disable-xlib --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-avisynth --enable-chromaprint --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --disable-libfdk-aac --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-frei0r --enable-libgme --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libaribcaption --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libjxl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librist --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-lv2 --enable-libvpl --enable-openal --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libuavs3d --disable-libdrm --enable-vaapi --enable-libvidstab --enable-vulkan --enable-libshaderc --enable-libplacebo --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --disable-doc --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-ldexeflags= --extra-libs=-lgomp --extra-version=20240114
  libavutil      58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavcodec     60. 31.102 / 60. 31.102
  libavformat    60. 16.100 / 60. 16.100
  libavdevice    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavfilter     9. 12.100 /  9. 12.100
  libswscale      7.  5.100 /  7.  5.100
  libswresample   4. 12.100 /  4. 12.100
  libpostproc    57.  3.100 / 57.  3.100
Input #0, image2, from 'D:/New folder (76)/Image_%04d.png':
  Duration: 00:00:02.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba(pc, gbr/unknown/unknown), 1536x2048, 0.50 fps, 0.50 tbr, 0.50 tbn
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> gif (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, gif, to 'D:/test.gif':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf60.16.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: gif, bgr8(pc, gbr/unknown/unknown, progressive), 1536x2048, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 0.50 fps, 100 tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc60.31.102 gif
[out#0/gif @ 0000016edfc34bc0] video:696kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000140%
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=     696kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
 
D:\Captured>


Since your file names have numbers with leading zeros, you should use the form %04d instead of %d. (Also you are missing an underscore before the %d).
From the documentation:

A sequence pattern may contain the string "%d" or "%0Nd", which specifies the position of the characters representing a sequential number in each filename matched by the pattern. If the form "%d0Nd" is used, the string representing the number in each filename is 0-padded and N is the total number of 0-padded digits representing the number.

If you use just %d, ffmpeg tries to find files like Image1.png, Image2.png, etc., which don't exist.
Your complete command would then be:
D:\Captured>ffmpeg -framerate 1/2 -start_number 1 -i "D:/New folder (76)/Image_%04d.png" -loop -1 D:/test.gif

Finally, I assume your files are indeed .png, it is not visible in your screenshot since you have extensions not showing. If not, you would have to correct that part too.

Update: After your comment, you figured out yourself that the file numbers were also not consecutive. The correct way to handle this is using -pattern_type glob, so in your case this would be:
D:\Captured>ffmpeg -framerate 1/2 -start_number 1 -pattern_type glob -i "D:/New folder (76)/Image_????.png" -loop -1 D:/test.gif

See also this answer

it's png you right and the command line worked but it created about 695kb file size image file not animated gif.

Can you try adding the option -f image2 and see if this helps?

actually, for me it works also without the -f image2, are you sure the generated gif has not all the frames? What viewer are you using, maybe that viewer can not show animated gifs and only shows the first frame?

i'm trying to open the animated gif with internet explorer ( edge )

You are using forward slash D:/New folder (76)/... but on Windows you should use back slash D:\New folder (76)...

@RicardoBohner this is new to me too, but it looks like windows supports / as path separator since a very long time. And since OP seemed to get some output with the forward slashes after he fixed the %04d I guessed ffmpeg handles that case, but it seems it is more generic behavior than just ffmpeg! In fact I just tried, and even in cmd I can type dir "c:/Users" and it works fine (quotes are needed though).

@gepa i found the problem and now it's working. sorry for the mess.  the problem was that the files names in the folder was not in a sequence order you can see it in the image screenshot in my question.  the first image file name is Image_0001 but the next one is Image_0004 there is no 0002 and not 0003 and ffmpeg does not know to continue if there is a gap between the names.  at least in windows ffmpeg. in Linux i think ffmpeg knows to create the animated gif file even if the files names not in a sequence.  anyway, after renaming the images names it's working.

@DanielLip right, I didn't notice this either in your screenshot (it behaves the same in linux btw). In this case you want to use -pattern_type glob. I updated my answer accordingly.

@gepa i tried glob before even before asking here without knowing the problem was the files names sequence but i'm getting error with the glob.  [image2 @ 000001d8e7dc10c0] Pattern type 'glob' was selected but globbing is not supported by this libavformat build  and i tried to find where to download or how to update the libavformat but didn't find.

-pattern_type glob is not working in Windows. You may try using concat demuxer when the numbers are not consecutive. Create a list of the files using a for loop: @echo ffconcat version 1.0 > mylist.txt && (for %i in ("D:\New folder (76)\Image_????.png") do @echo file '%i' && @echo duration 2.0) >> mylist.txt. Then use concat demuxer with the list as input: ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -loop -1 D:/test.gif
